Angular v16: JS Memory and RAM Memory are not releasing when I switch the route
I have a very strange and interesting problem: for one of my page when I switch from it to another route I see that the memory stays the same and when I go to the same route the memory increases twice and if I do those steps few times than for big amount of data I will get Page Unresponsive dialog very quickly.
OnDestroy lifehook for every component from the component tree runs as expected.
App Techs: Angular v16 and PrimeNg.
Env: Monorepo.
What we did:

cleared subscriptions;
cleared data;
searched for memory leaks in components, fixed what we found;
put takeUntil pipe in the end on pipes with switching map;

I expect the memory is releasing when user changes the route.

This will be very difficult to help without reproduction. Is OnDestroy called when you navigate away?

Yes, definitely.
But steps are similar: Page 1 (Memory 150Mb) -> Page 2(Memory the same) -> Page 1 (Memory 300Mb) -> Page 2 (Memory 300Mb).
BUT if I reload the page memory releases.
I cannot share my code :(

Could you check if Route Reuse Strategy has any impact on the performance?

@DmMh we use default reuse strategy, so It does not have impact on performance.
